# Is there a Chrome extension to remove certain domains/websites from Google results?

Tags: google-chrome-extensions

I would like certain websites to be removed from Google results, since they simply waste my time. I generally avoid clicking them, but it would be nice if there was an extension for it.

For the curious, I'm not interested in sites such as Yahoo Answers, Experts Exchange and eFreedom.

Comment: Google now supports this natively. It's called "Blocked Sites": http://www.google.com/reviews/t

Comment: Sadly, Google removed the "blocked sites" functionality...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe this?

https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/ddgjlkmkllmpdhegaliddgplookikmjf

or this
https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/eidhkmnbiahhgbgpjpiimdogfidfikgf

here is how I found them, kind of ironic.
https://encrypted.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=filter+google+resules+in+chrome

.

Comment: "Google Search Filter" works great!

Answer (score 0):

There is also [Personal Blocklist (by Google)](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/personal-blocklist-by-goo/nolijncfnkgaikbjbdaogikpmpbdcdef?hl=en) which I personally use.